# Putting Qur'an beside your head when sleeping

Tags: quran, dream

Assalamualaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu

I had many people says to me that if you put Qur'an beside your head or read some verse before sleeping, you will not have bad dream or any nightmares.

I this true and by which source

Comment: I've never heard this without a source it might hardly be considerd as given. IMHO it is doubtful as if this was true the prophet would have told us, when speaking about dreams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no evidence of this in the Quran and Sunnah. Thus, it is baseless and an innovation, and one should refrain from it. The only way one can benefit from the Quran is by reading, understanding, and implementing its verses.

The Sunnah in seeking protection in Allah SWT before sleeping can be found here:

[Sunnah before sleeping](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/145543)